# Facebook Send button empty flyout

Tags: javascript, facebook

I have a Facebook XFBML *Like* and *Send* button.
The code is generated with [Facebook like plugin](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like/) .
*Like* seems to work well, but *Send* only display an empty flyout.
**Example**
http://jsfiddle.net/CVDLc/1/
*Click on the Send button to see the empty flyout*
Anyone have an idea why?

Comment: A friend of mine, mentionned me that even on the [Facebook like plugin page](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like/) the _Send Button_ display an empty flyout

Comment: I can't repro an empty flyout, but your symptoms sound like this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10865122/facebook-send-button-opens-a-blank-box

Comment: Ok, this is being tracked by FB here:  https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/110650839093215

Comment: Thanks @DonnLee I'll stop searching for now :)